# Skipping '0' values in an array: An issue creating an svg graph

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, svg, graph

I've got stuck, some help would be much appreciated…

http://onemorechris.co.uk/x/spreadsheettest2.php I'm displaying year, month & day data from a Google spreadsheet & creating graphs with Snap SVG. The graph shows day values for each month, some are '0' giving sharp spikes on the graph…

Is there a way to 'skip' days of the month where the value is 0 and draw the svg points from one point directly to the next while still plotting points across the graph with the correct spacing? This image shows the kind effect I'm after vs what I currently have > http://onemorechris.co.uk/x/graphIssue.jpg

```
function graphMonthCreator() {
var MaxDayDistance = 3700;
var distancesForGraphMonthArray = [null]; 

//convert distances in meters into % of MaxDistance, invert the % & convert it into a % for minGraphHeight
var currMonthDistance = eval('distancesArray' + currYear + '_' + currMonth);
for (g=0; g<currMonthDistance.length; g++) {
    distancesForGraphMonthArray.push(Math.round(minGraphHeight / 100 * ((100 - (currMonthDistance[g] / MaxDayDistance * 100)))));
}

//if month has less than 31 days, add extra 0 days so graph is always '31 days long'
for (a=29;a<=31;a++) {
    if (distancesForGraphMonthArray[a] == undefined) {
        distancesForGraphMonthArray.push(minGraphHeight);
    }
}

//start graph as a flat line 4px high
var array = [svgOffset,160,svgOffset,minGraphHeight,
(graphArrayDays[1]+svgOffset),minGraphHeight,
(graphArrayDays[2]+svgOffset),minGraphHeight,
(graphArrayDays[3]+svgOffset),minGraphHeight,
(graphArrayDays[4]+svgOffset),minGraphHeight,
(graphArrayDays[5]+svgOffset),minGraphHeight,
(graphArrayDays[6]+svgOffset),minGraphHeight,
(graphArrayDays[7]+svgOffset),minGraphHeight,
(graphArrayDays[8]+svgOffset),minGraphHeight,
(graphArrayDays[9]+svgOffset),minGraphHeight,
(graphArrayDays[10]+svgOffset),minGraphHeight,
(graphArrayDays[11]+svgOffset),minGraphHeight,
(graphArrayDays[12]+svgOffset),minGraphHeight,
(graphArrayDays[13]+svgOffset),minGraphHeight,
(graphArrayDays[14]+svgOffset),minGraphHeight,
(graphArrayDays[15]+svgOffset),minGraphHeight,
(graphArrayDays[16]+svgOffset),minGraphHeight,
(graphArrayDays[17]+svgOffset),minGraphHeight,
(graphArrayDays[18]+svgOffset),minGraphHeight,
(graphArrayDays[19]+svgOffset),minGraphHeight,
(graphArrayDays[20]+svgOffset),minGraphHeight,
(graphArrayDays[21]+svgOffset),minGraphHeight,
(graphArrayDays[22]+svgOffset),minGraphHeight,
(graphArrayDays[23]+svgOffset),minGraphHeight,
(graphArrayDays[24]+svgOffset),minGraphHeight,
(graphArrayDays[25]+svgOffset),minGraphHeight,
(graphArrayDays[26]+svgOffset),minGraphHeight,
(graphArrayDays[27]+svgOffset),minGraphHeight,
(graphArrayDays[28]+svgOffset),minGraphHeight,
(graphArrayDays[29]+svgOffset),minGraphHeight,
(graphArrayDays[30]+svgOffset),minGraphHeight,
(graphArrayDays[31]+svgOffset),minGraphHeight,
(graphArrayDays[31]+svgOffset),160];

//graph for individual months   
var graph2 = s2.polygon(array);
graph2.attr({
    id:'graphMonth',
    fill: '#DA4748',
    'opacity': 1
});

//animate graph to points from array
graph2.animate({"points":[svgOffset,160,svgOffset,minGraphHeight,
(graphArrayDays[1]+svgOffset),distancesForGraphMonthArray[1],
(graphArrayDays[2]+svgOffset),distancesForGraphMonthArray[2],
(graphArrayDays[3]+svgOffset),distancesForGraphMonthArray[3],
(graphArrayDays[4]+svgOffset),distancesForGraphMonthArray[4],
(graphArrayDays[5]+svgOffset),distancesForGraphMonthArray[5],
(graphArrayDays[6]+svgOffset),distancesForGraphMonthArray[6],
(graphArrayDays[7]+svgOffset),distancesForGraphMonthArray[7],
(graphArrayDays[8]+svgOffset),distancesForGraphMonthArray[8],
(graphArrayDays[9]+svgOffset),distancesForGraphMonthArray[9],
(graphArrayDays[10]+svgOffset),distancesForGraphMonthArray[10],
(graphArrayDays[11]+svgOffset),distancesForGraphMonthArray[11],
(graphArrayDays[12]+svgOffset),distancesForGraphMonthArray[12],
(graphArrayDays[13]+svgOffset),distancesForGraphMonthArray[13],
(graphArrayDays[14]+svgOffset),distancesForGraphMonthArray[14],
(graphArrayDays[15]+svgOffset),distancesForGraphMonthArray[15],
(graphArrayDays[16]+svgOffset),distancesForGraphMonthArray[16],
(graphArrayDays[17]+svgOffset),distancesForGraphMonthArray[17],
(graphArrayDays[18]+svgOffset),distancesForGraphMonthArray[18],
(graphArrayDays[19]+svgOffset),distancesForGraphMonthArray[19],
(graphArrayDays[20]+svgOffset),distancesForGraphMonthArray[20],
(graphArrayDays[21]+svgOffset),distancesForGraphMonthArray[21],
(graphArrayDays[22]+svgOffset),distancesForGraphMonthArray[22],
(graphArrayDays[23]+svgOffset),distancesForGraphMonthArray[23],
(graphArrayDays[24]+svgOffset),distancesForGraphMonthArray[24],
(graphArrayDays[25]+svgOffset),distancesForGraphMonthArray[25],
(graphArrayDays[26]+svgOffset),distancesForGraphMonthArray[26],
(graphArrayDays[27]+svgOffset),distancesForGraphMonthArray[27],
(graphArrayDays[28]+svgOffset),distancesForGraphMonthArray[28],
(graphArrayDays[29]+svgOffset),distancesForGraphMonthArray[29],
(graphArrayDays[30]+svgOffset),distancesForGraphMonthArray[30],
(graphArrayDays[31]+svgOffset),distancesForGraphMonthArray[31],
(graphArrayDays[31]+svgOffset),160
]},900,mina.easeinout);}
```

Comment: somewhere a `for` loop did not get its magic wings today

Comment: I'm aware of the lack of loopage. Snap SVG doesnt seem to want to play nicely with loops, no doubt this is compounding the problem I'm looking to address

Comment: I think the kind of logic im looking for is: IF 'i' in array = 0, (i-1) - (i+1) = mid way point. (i-1) array position - (i+1) array position * 16px = x position for graph. (Im aware is is wrong, but getting closer to the solution)